# Prove that the way to partition N as a summation from the natural set is $2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n \geq 1$, show that it can be written as a summation from $\mathbb{N}$ in ordered way in $2^{n-1}$ ways. I'm trying to give both inductive proof and combinatorial.

For inductive:

$P_1$: This is the base case when $ n = 1$ the ways are: $|\{\{1\}\}| = 1 = 2 ^ {1-1}$

Let's assume $P_n$ holds, that $n$ can be represented in $2^{n-1}$ ways.

$P_n \implies P_{n+1}$

Now I am stuck. I know that we can add 1 to all the summations that we have for $n$ to obtain $n+1$ but I know there may be also other ways and I don't know how to count for the fact that the choices are ordered.

Can someone give me a hint or help me out, thanks.

Comment: $(1  \color{red}{)}+\color{red}{(} 1\color{red}{)}+\color{red}{(} 1\color{red}{)}+\color{red}{(} 1 \dots \color{red}{)}+\color{red}{(} 1)$.  Pick which if any of the red parentheses you use.

Comment: As for an inductive approach., moving from a summation of $n$ to a summation of $n+1$ the final $+1$ could either appear by itself, or it could be included added into the final term of the summation.  E.g. $1+3+2+3\mapsto \begin{cases}1+3+2+3+1\\1+3+2+4\end{cases}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Why just consider it can be added to the final term, can't it be added to any term of the summation and also appear by itself?

Comment: @JMoravitz like for 3 one possibility is {1, 1, 1} now for 4 by itself we can have {1, 1, 1, 1} or +1 to any of the terms like {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2} since order matters they all count?

Comment: The point is to try to come up with a bijection between the set of possible summations for $(n+1)$ and the cartesian product of the set of possible summations for $(n)$ and $\{0,1\}$.  With $1,1,1$ as the initial sequence, we only want to consider $1,1,1,1$ and $1,1,2$ as the possible new sequences created from that to avoid overlap.  Meanwhile $2,1$ leads to either of $2,1,1$ or $2,2$.  Similarly $1,2$ leads to either of $1,2,1$ or $1,3$, etc... so, to help us avoid overcounting, we can choose to *only* append the $1$ to the end of the sequence or add it to *only* the final term.

Comment: We get, as expected, exactly twice as many possible sequences of positive integers adding to $n+1$ as we had sequences adding to $n$, yielding the desired result.

Comment: @JMoravitz From observation I can see that we generate overlaps if we add it to any other term except the last but I can't show it rigorously. Now I am onto combinatorial proof - any hint for that?

Comment: We don't generate overlaps because if two resulting sequences are both the same, they either both end with a $1$ in which case they must have been both created by the same sequence without that final $1$, or they both end without a $1$ in which case they must have both been created by the same sequence where the final entry is one less.  That every sequence can be successfully created should be obvious, but can be proven with induction.  Just keep removing one from the final entry if greater than one, or removing final entry if it is a one.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine $n$ dots in a line, and let $G$ be the set of the $n-1$ interior gaps between consecutive dots. For any subset $S$ of $G$, there is a canonical ordered partition for which each part counts the consecutive dots between elements of  $S$ (like "stars and bars"). It's easy to see this is a bijection between the partitions and subsets of $G$. How many subsets $S$ of $G$ are there altogether?

For an inductive argument, given a partition $P$ of $n-1$ (for example $6=4+2$), generate two partitions of $n$ as follows (1) add 1 to the last part of $P$ (e.g. $7=4+3$) and (2) insert a "$+1$" at the end of $P$ (e.g. $7=4+2+1$). The first type are the partitions of $n$ that don't end with a $1$ and the second type are the ones that do end with a $1$. So there are twice as many partitions of $n$ as of $n-1$.